# How to use method chaining in PHP7 with proper error handling

Tags: php-7

I have nested objects and method calls like this for an XML web service:

```
$value = $object->getData()->getSomething()->getValue();
```

The problem is, if one nested object does not exists, there is an Error thrown like this:

```
Call to a member function getData() on null
```

Can I avoid having silly code like this:

```
if ($object && $object->getData() && $object->getData()->getSomething()) {
   $value = $object->getData()->getSomething()->getValue();
}
```

or catching an Error:

```
try {
   $value = $object->getData()->getSomething()->getValue();
} catch (Error $e) {

}
```

The best would be something like:

```
if (isset($object->getData()->getSomething())) {
   $value = $object->getData()->getSomething()->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PHP 8 it is possible now:

```
$value = $object?->getData()?->getSomething()?->getValue();
```

Explanation [PHP8 Nullsafe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator):

When the left hand side of the operator evaluates to null the execution of the entire chain will stop and evalute to null.